# how to do REDIRECT after NFQUEUE

Tags: iptables

there is a set of rules that worked well:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i $lan_if -o $nat_if -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
iptables -A FORWARD -i $nat_if -o $lan_if -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
iptables -t nat -A PLACEMENT -o $nat_if -j MASQUERADE
```

however after NFQUEUE it took REDIRECT, I added a rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i $lan_if -o $nat_if -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
iptables -A FORWARD -i $nat_if -o $lan_if -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s $pc_ip -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081

iptables -t nat -A PLACEMENT -o $nat_if -j MASQUERADE
```

but NFQUEUE stopped working, this is because PREROUTING occurs before NFQUEUE.

how to make traffic go through NFQUEUE first and only then REDIRECT?

attempts to replace FORWARD with PREROUTING failed:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i $lan_if -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

and

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $lan_if -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

doesn't work like that

for packets, you need to build the following route:

1. from the $lan_if interface, packets should go to the NFQUEUE --queue-num 0 queue (monitoring)
2. after that, the packets should go to REDIRECT --to-port 8081 (proxying)

i want to find a working example code where NFQUEUE works before REDIRECT

perhaps I need to somehow split the stream into different queues executed sequentially. I'm just not good at iptables so I don't know how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

According to the IPTables structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg

`PREROUTING` chain is processed before the `filter` table `FORWARD` chain. Therefore this rule takes place first.

To process packet using `NFQUEUE` before `REDIRECT`, you must place the jump to `NFQUEUE` in `PREROUTING` chain before the `REDIRECT` rule.

However, your application that uses `NFQUEUE` might work differently with this setup.